# java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getNString(int) is not yet implemented

Tags: java

```
GRAVE: null

java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getNString(int) is not yet implemented.

    at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:643)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getNString(PgResultSet.java:3519)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getNString(PgResultSet.java:3523)
    at practica_bd.interfaz_listar_clientes.listar(interfaz_listar_clientes.java:55)
    at practica_bd.interfaz_listar_clientes.<init>(interfaz_listar_clientes.java:22)
    at practica_bd.Practica_BD.main(Practica_BD.java:19)
```

Comment: You may have to update the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

It means that your postgresql driver can't do that operation. You should either update to use a different driver/database, or don't use that method.

This is because of following reasons:

- no support for an optional feature
- no support for an optional overloaded method
- no support for an optional mode for a method. The mode for a method is determined based on constants passed as parameter values to a method

[For more details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLFeatureNotSupportedException.html)